# how to run combined commands in monodevelop

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

I want to run combined commands like:

```
    echo hello world | nano test.txt
```

I've tried doing:

```
    Process.Start ("echo", "hello world | nano test.txt");
```

But got no luck with that.
How do we run such processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with any programming language that accepts process - argument
since that you tagged "linux" you can use bash.. 
consider changing it if you want to use another shell

Comment: thanks for this explaination.. you solved my problem